# How to avoid switches?

Tags: php, mvc, laravel

I use Laravel as a PHP framework, although the question is not exactly about laravel, more about structuring controller methods.

I have a route to orders page. Depending on the user role I need to include different views and I have different logic for each role. It looks like this:

```
    public function index()
    {
        switch ($this->user->role->name) {
            case 'admin': {
                // Some code
                break;
            }
            case 'customer': {
                // Some code
                break;
            }
            case 'manager': {
                // Some code
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I repeat this pattern for all routes which are accessible for many roles. I know that using repeatedly `if`/`else`, `switch` or this kind of stuff is not the best solution. Also the function becomes quite big (not much but depends on logic). Of course I can break it into 3 subfunctions lie (`indexAdmin`, `indexManager`, `indexCustomer`) but am still not sure if it's good.

Could anybody explain how to deal with it, preferably using Laravel (I use 5 dev version)?

**Update**

Here is the full code: http://laravel.io/bin/eDkmj

Comment: Well, when we consider just some abstract examples with Classes & OOP & Polymorphism, I understand what is in this link. But I absolutely cannot understand how to apply polymorphism in such MVC structure. I wouldn't like to create AdminOrderController, CustomerOrderConstoller etc...

Comment: The "some code" is the most important part!  It's the behaviour that presumably is different depending on role. If you could give us an example of what that difference is and help us to understand the behaviour then we can provide more advice.

Comment: Okay, I've added the full version of code. Usually it's something like that, I use different filters (where, orwhere), fetch only those orders which belong to somebody or fetch all orders for admin etc. Sometimes it becomes too long. I know I can actually move the code into model, thought I don't think the model should work with Input, and also I don't want to make a function with arguments like: function getOrders($managerId = null, $searchString = null ... ). So, how to deal with this code and how to make it look pretty? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a first step, you can move the code blocks in the switch to functions of their own and call those functions from the switch. After that you could try to think of a more automatic mechanism of mapping the role to the role-specific function to call.

Comment: I'm not really seeing a problem here. You could move your roles over to a database table, along with anything configurable about them, and then range over them. I would also try to break up some of the code into functions. What's the problem with a switch, again?

Comment: Well, when asking google about "why switches are bad" I always find some examples with polymorphism. But I've found no practical examples how to use that technique in my case. Of course the code works and I don't have any problems right now, except that it grows. But still, I don't use unit-testing at all, and right now when I read about it I'm a little bit concerned about how hard it will be to test such methods

Answer (score -1):

I think that break into 3 functions like you said is the best alternative, mainly to separate the logic of each user.

Here's an example of how this can be made:

```
public function index() {
    $method = "index" . ucfirst($this->user->role->name);
    $this->$method();
}

private function indexAdmin() {
    // do stuff
}

private function indexCustomer() {
    // do stuff
}

private function indexManager() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: As elegant as this approach may seem, it becomes *very* difficult to do any sort of static analysis on it to see where a given method is called from (even search won't find where `indexAdmin()` is invoked).  This also has the possibility of opening up other security issues in the application if unintended functions can be invoked.